# path-here comand in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have basic NetLogo command questions.

I would like a set of mobile agents (turtles) to access a patch variable (called veg) and collect a certain amount of (sugar) according to their ability to load sugar (size). I'm trying to use the patch-here command, but there are no examples of how to use the patch-here in the NetLogo dictionary, and I don't know how I can ask the turtles a question to ask if they have collected enough sugar from that patch base on your size. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do or where can I find this information?

```
 ask turtles [
    patch-here veg > 0.6 
    set sugar (sugar - metabolism)    
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `patch-here`, you would modify your code to:

```
ask turtles
[ if [veg] of patch-here > 0.6 
  [ set sugar (sugar - metabolism)    
  ]
]
```

However, each turtle is located at one patch - even if the picture used to show the turtle is huge and crosses many patches, the turtle itself is considered to be located at a single point, which is within one patch. NetLogo uses the coordinate system in a clever way - because the turtle can only be at one place, if you use a patch variable name, it will assume that you want the patch where the turtle is located.

So you could simplify that to:

```
ask turtles
[ if veg > 0.6 
  [ set sugar (sugar - metabolism)    
  ]
]
```

Note that I removed the [ ] when I removed the `of patch-here`.

But you can simplify that further to:

```
ask turtles with [veg > 0.6]
[ set sugar (sugar - metabolism)    
]
```

So if you are using `patch-here` to get the variable value of the patch where the turtle is located, then you can just use the variable directly. A typical use of `patch-here` is to find other turtles on the same patch.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are asking turtles, you can't access the patch variable directly, you need to access the patch first before you can access the variable inside the patch.

```
ask bees
  [ ask patch-here
    [ if veg > 0.6
      [ set sugar (sugar - metabolism) ]
    ]
  ]
```

Or you can simplify the code using [of](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/of.html) command and use the patch-here as the location of the patch you want to check.

```
ask bees
  [ if [veg] of patch-here > 0.6
    [ set sugar (sugar - metabolism) ]]
```

Comment: this is not actually true, a turtle can access the patch variables of `patch-here` directly